# Creating a reusable control which can be embedded in UIViews and handle its own modals

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

There's a particular control which I'm trying to build properly.  I refer to it as an ImageTile.  It's basically a little square box, which, when the user taps it, will present the user (via an action sheet in a popover) the option of selecting an image from the library, or taking a photo.  Depending on the response, I then either present the UIImagePickerController inside a popover (for selecting an image) or modally (for taking a new picture).  Once they take/select the image, I have a modal view which appears and allows them to edit the picture in a few simple ways.  When they finish editing, the modal dismisses, and the original ImageTile, rather than being a blank square box, gets filled up with the user's edited image.

The issue is that this ImageTile control is going to be used profusely throughout several different parts of the application, across numerous View Controller hierarchies, and so on... and I really want it to be a basically totally self-contained unit, such that whenever I stick an ImageTile inside a UIView onscreen, all the above functionality is handled by the ImageTile itself.

Initially, I made it a UIViewController subclass (so it could present modals etc), and just added its view as a subview of a "holder" view onscreen.  I know this isn't recommended, as the controller isn't part of the VC hierarchy then... and also, I wound up with some really weird behavior regarding things like autorotation, especially when the camera was involved.

What's the "right" way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you've done by making it a `UIViewController` subclass is correct.  You should just use the methods that `UIViewController` exposes for adding child view controllers, such as  [- addChildViewController:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController:).

You will also note that Interface Builder has a Container View object designed specifically for holding a place in the hierarchy for a child View Controller:

[image]